# Relative Wifi performance: iPhone 5 and iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi

I noticed that my iPhone's Wifi performance sometimes lagged and so I did an experiment. From exactly the same place in my living room, within seconds of each other, my iPad showed around 6Mb down and my iPhone 5 showed less than half that, around 2.5Mb.

Can someone suggest why they think this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's relative to your problem. But I was experiencing some problems with my iPhone 5 Wifi signal and down performance. I found that some iPhone 5 users were experiencing the same problem, due to a WiFi connection configuration. So what they did was just reset the network configuration on the **General settings**.

Check the following link from Apple Support site:
[iOS: Troubleshooting Wi-Fi networks and connections](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1398)

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing what iPad you have, it likely has a different CPU and Wireless chipset. It also could have differing RAM and workloads - although they usually are not a blocking or even major factor in download tests.

Comment: It's the new iPad...